# ¿Cómo configuro un npm token como variable de entorno?

Tags: npm

En el trabajo me han requerido usar un token de npm para poder acceder a los paquetes privados de la organización, he leído la [documentación](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow/) de npm sobre la configuración de las mismas, pero mi duda es la siguiente:

**No entiendo cómo setear el token como variable de entorno sin tener que colocarlo en el archivo .env, que es lo que indica la documentación.**

**Me encuentro trabajando con bitbucket.**

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro si el dato de que tu organización usa BitBucket implica que necesitas un token del registro BitBucket en tu máquina local, o un token de otro registro en el pipeline de BitBucket, o ambas cosas.

Para lo primero, entonces en tu `.bashrc` podrías poner

```
  export NPM_TOKEN='asdfd...'
```

Pero ten presente que también podrías declararlo inline, con

```
  NPM_TOKEN=asdfdgg...   npm install
```

Y hasta crear un alias en tu `.bash_aliases` para prefijarlo implícitamente a cualquier ejecución de npm (o yarn, si prefieres)

```
  alias npm='NPM_TOKEN=asdff...  npm'
```

Y cuando digo tu `.bashrc` o tu `.bash_aliases` quiero decir los que correspondan al usuario que se usa para instalar, como el caso del usuario `pm2` que recomiendan usar para el homónimo process manager.

Si te referías en cambio a cómo acceder a la variable de entorno en  el pipeline, entonces guíate por la documentación [que aparece en BitBucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/), donde lo medular es el uso de secrets para dejar ese token en la organización o en el repo del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es de paso muy parecido a lo que se haría en el panel de Heroku.

---

Yo imagino que en cualquiera de esos escenarios el propósito de la variable de entorno es usarla en un archivo `.npmrc` en la raíz del proyecto. Por ejemplo (si estuviésemos hablando de Github Packages) con algo como

```
 //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Puesto que la existencia del token en el entorno no es suficiente para que npm o yarn sepan usarlo.